# Allow another user to access my Oracle table

Tags: oracle

I would simply like to allow a colleague to view and edit the Database I've created.

I've tried:

```
GRANT ALL on FISHTABLE to JDOE;
```

and it returned `Grant succeeded` but nothing changed for him and he still wasn't able to view my table.

I also tried

`GRANT SELECT smahala.fishtable to jdoe@example.org;`

but that failed with `SQL Error: ORA_00990: missing or invalid privilege`.

Is my issue that I don't have the administrative authority to allow someone else to view my Oracle table? Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Has he tried "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM smahala.fishtable;"? If you grant select on a table in one schema to another schema that user should be able to access it by including the schema name in the query. However, if NOAA is using virtual private databases, then there may be other obstacles that prevent you from sharing data. If there isn't much data, you can try to export to a flat file and have the other person import the flat file. but this should probably get resolved by your internal DBA's. Since they know how the database is configured. You might also want to verify that you are using the same Oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

The second grant statement you provide should be

```
GRANT SELECT ON fishtable TO <oracle username or role name>;
```

Note the *On* keyword and that it should be to an oracle user or role and not to an email address.